# C# with MySQL Table is specified twice, both as a target for 'UPDATE'

Tags: c#, mysql

This is my SQL query

```
UPDATE Nomina 
SET utilidadSemana = 
    (SELECT SUM(totalIngresosXSemana - totalGastosXSemana) 
        FROM Nomina 
        WHERE fechaInicio >= @fechaInicial 
        AND fechaFin <= @fechaFinal) 
WHERE 
    fechaInicio >= @fechaInicial 
    AND fechaFin <= @fechaFinal;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your dates are constants, so you can use `CROSS JOIN`:

```
UPDATE Nomina n CROSS JOIN
       (SELECT SUM(totalIngresosXSemana - totalGastosXSemana) as newval
        FROM Nomina 
        WHERE fechaInicio >= @fechaInicial AND
              fechaFin <= @fechaFinal
       ) nn
    SET n.utilidadSemana = nn.newval   
WHERE fechaInicio >= @fechaInicial AND
      fechaFin <= @fechaFinal;
```